# Unreal Engine 5 everything is white on the screen

Tags: c++, game-development, unreal-engine4

I tried to make a collision for my camera, but when I launch the editor, this happens:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IXS5.jpg)
All textures on the screen are white and glowing.
When I try to play this level in the active level editor viewport, it gives an error message:

[2024-01-14T13:25:28.265Z]LogUnrealMath: Error: TMatrix::InverseFast(), trying to invert a non-invertible matrix, this results in NaNs! Use Inverse() instead.

and

[2024-01-14T13:25:28.266Z]LogOutputDevice: Error: Ensure condition failed: false

[File:D:\build++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\Math\Matrix.h] [Line: 449]
[2024-01-14T13:25:28.266Z]LogOutputDevice: Error: TMatrix::InverseFast(), trying to invert a non-invertible matrix, this results in NaNs!

In fact, I don’t know what to do anymore, reversing the code doesn’t help
It is the contructor of my camera class

```
PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

SceneComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<USceneComponent>(TEXT("Scene Component"));
SetRootComponent(SceneComponent);   // set root


SpringArmComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<USpringArmComponent>(TEXT("SpringArmComponent"));   // creating spring arm component
SpringArmComponent->TargetArmLength =100.0f; // set length of spring arm component
SpringArmComponent->bDoCollisionTest = true; // switch on collision
SpringArmComponent->SetupAttachment(RootComponent); // set root

CameraComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<UCameraComponent>(TEXT("Camera of Player")); // creating camera of player
CameraComponent->SetupAttachment(SpringArmComponent); // set camera to the spring arm component
```

I think that it is the problem